# aggragator website - mirroring content changes with automation

Tags: javascript, php, web-scraping, automation

I am building an aggragator website. Using www.nbcnews.com as an example, their "number one story" is a big picture with some text. That links you to the actual article. I want to mirror that picture and text on my site as well. Of course I could also set a static link on my website to that image and text. However when they change their "number one story" then mine will still be that static link to the old story. Is there a way to automate the process? Every time their "number one" story updates, I want my number one story to mirror that change.

Is there a php or java solution for this that does not use a web scraper??

Below is a stripped down example of a blank page with the static link set up I am talking about.

BTW there is no RSS feed and no API. This is also legal due to Fair Use laws and the fact when you click, it links back to the authors website.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<div style="height: 400px; width: 900px; border: 2px red solid"><a href="http://www.nbcnews.com/politics/2016-election/donald-trump-s-strange-surprise-last-minute-jaunt-mexico-n640686"><img src="http://media4.s-nbcnews.com/j/newscms/2016_35/1690621/160831-trump-pena-nieto-mn-0851_697c23fc65b3e981f879e0302b490899.nbcnews-fp-600-320.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt=""/></a> 
</div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Google or search this site for how to crawl websites *or* check if they provide an api *or* check if they provide an rss feed.

Comment: There is no API or rss feed. I also dont know of a way to edit an rss feed to limit it to just the lead story and then use the main image only. Would the only way to do this be create a scraper?

Comment: check your not violating the sites TOS. You probably are

Comment: I am not. Please look up fair use.

Comment: your wrong about there being no rss: http://feeds.nbcnews.com/feeds/topstories that should make this rather simple

Comment: Thanks. I am merely using nbcnews as an example. I am not actually using their site. The site I am linking to, does not have an API or rss feed.

Answer (score -1):

It is not very hard to do if u think about it. First of all i have done it in python and i just needed two libraries to make it work. Request and lxml python library. Request was used to go to the actual web page and lxml was used to scrap the portion of html snippet off the website and you would need to write one function to transform the return value from lxml library to a data structure that you can use for your website.

Comment: Thanks. That makes some sense to me but I am sure I can google or search here to fill in the blanks. I dont know python at all. Is there a php solution or javascript solution for grabbing that one spot?

Comment: I mentioned python because they are very much like php but much cleaner syntax. You can definitely find the python equivalent librariea in php or javascript.